# Laravel store views cache to Redis

Tags: caching, redis, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5 with CACHE_DRIVER redis.
I found that there are still Views cache files under /storage/framework/views/.
Is it possible to store Views cache in redis? I thought that it will speed up the website.
Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Laravel 5 doesn't support this. config/view.php is rather stubby and makes no mention of drivers, whereas config/session.php and config/cache.php both have keys that make use of CACHE_DRIVER.

You can store the view cache files in a custom location on the filesystem, but other than that, at time of writing, there's not much else you can do with the views configuration.